# "udevd[96]: timeout:" error killing blkid when booting from a Live CD

Tags: 11.10, installation, live-cd, cd

I have a Dell Inspiron 4100 and keep getting the following error when attempting a Ubuntu trial on a CD.

`udevd[96]: timeout: killing '/sbin/blkid -o udev -p /dev/sda' [121]`

Eventually, I am taken to a screen that says Ubuntu with five flashing dots underneath but it doesn't progress further.

Side notes: the hard drive in the laptop is failing, hence why I am trying to boot from CD. The cd was burned on a Mac.  The computer is too old to boot from USB.

Thank you do much for your help!

Comment: Did you check the disk image (md5sum) after downloading?  Did you check the CD after burning? Can the CD be used to boot up on another computer?

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!